# CONCAT from two fields

Tags: mysql, triggers, concatenation

Wanting to `CONCAT` two columns to make a new ID, as per the image.

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsdRO.png)

The Trigger statement I have is: And I have tried Trigger INSERT and UPDATE events.

[Trigger statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9LK2.png)

```
SET new.img_url_id = CONCAT(new.img_metadata_id, new.mag_name_id)
```

The Trigger statement returns values in the 'mag_name_id' field (10). The Trigger has to happen after field 'img_metadata_id' is inserted because 'img_metadata_id' is auto-incremented, and after 'mag_name_id' is inserted, it's pulled from another table. Changing the Trigger time to After, PHPMyAdmin gives an error. Do I need to do a Procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message you get? How is `mag_name_id` "pulled from another table"?

Comment: Im not getting any error, its just '10' being inserted into 'img_url_id' and not 188910, 189010 .... etc. Field 'mag_name_id' is inserted using python, it takes the ID from another table.

Comment: and you need to get this concatenated id when record is inserted or when updated, or both?

Comment: and it is MySQL?

Comment: What version of MySql?

Comment: The database is MariaDB, version: 10.3.12-MariaDB-1:10.3.12+maria~xenial-log - mariadb.org binary distribution (using phpmyadmin).
Peter, re concat ID. When a record is created, an AI is made and the 'mage_name_id' is made (from python).. After that, the 'img_url_id' can be made. So I guessing an UPDATE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (but that said, this sounds like a terrible idea)

Comment: @riot12 And this is made in one step, when a new record is inserted by Python with setting `mage_name_id`, or separately, there is first and insert, and then somehow the record is updated with `mage_name_id`?

Comment: @PeterKoltai - made in one step when a record is inserted. Now thinking its not possible as the table update is to quick to concatenate. When mag_name_id is inserted (python), img_metadata_id is inserted from AI,  then has to make the img_url_id before the next row is inserted.